# wix installer / Create web-site and assign the new or exisiting web app pool

Tags: web, wix, application-pool

i try create a new web-site using wix installation. it's ok there is no problem but i cannot assign a new or existing web app pool to new web-site. iis:website tag does not contains WebAppPool attribute. How can i assign web app pool to web-site. You can see my code bellow.

thanks for helping.

```xml
        <Component Id="WEB_SITE_CONFIGURE_COMPONENT" Guid="{35087032-D049-48C8-BCAD-1FEFD0C06A25}" NeverOverwrite="yes" Shared="yes" Permanent="yes" Transitive="yes">
          <Condition><![CDATA[WEBSITE_INSTALLTYPE<>2]]></Condition>
          <CreateFolder Directory="WEBSITE_FOLDER"/>
          <iis:WebSite Id="WEB_SITE" Description="[WEBSITE_NAME]" SiteId="*" Directory="WEBSITE_FOLDER" ConfigureIfExists="yes" AutoStart="yes" StartOnInstall="yes">
            <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[WEBSITE_PORT]" />            
          </iis:WebSite>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.DefaultRegistryKey)" Name="ConfigSite" Value="1" Type="string"></RegistryValue>
        </Component>        

        <Component Id="WEBAPP_POOL_CONFIGURE_COMPONENT" Guid="{316738A6-26A2-4C14-9AB9-B2066E3FA288}" KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes" Transitive="yes">
          <Condition><![CDATA[(WEBSITE_INSTALLTYPE=0) OR (USE_CUSTOM_WEBSITE_FOLDER=1)]]></Condition>          
          <iis:WebAppPool Id="APP_POOL" Name="[WEBAPP_POOL_NAME]" ManagedPipelineMode="Classic" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.DefaultRegistryKey)" Name="ConfigPool" Value="1" Type="string"></RegistryValue>
        </Component>

        <Component Id="WEPAPP_CONFIGURE_COMPONENT" Guid="{F95B024E-B6B6-4E6C-AC35-9B1086FC3521}" Transitive="yes">
          <Condition><![CDATA[(WEBSITE_INSTALLTYPE<>2) AND ((WEBSITE_INSTALLTYPE=0) OR (USE_CUSTOM_WEBSITE_FOLDER=1))]]></Condition>
          <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VIRTUAL_DIR" Alias="[WEB_APP_NAME]" Directory="WWW_FOLDER" WebSite="WEB_SITE">
            <iis:WebApplication Id="WEB_APP" Name="[WEB_APP_NAME]" WebAppPool="APP_POOL"/>            
          </iis:WebVirtualDir>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="$(var.DefaultRegistryKey)" Name="ConfigVirtualDir" Value="1" Type="string"></RegistryValue>
        </Component>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the following articles I have come up with a working installer in which a new AppPool can be created or an existing AppPool can be selected.

1. [Creating a Web Application Installer with WIX 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010–Part 1](http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2011/02/20/creating-a-web-application-installer-with-wix-3.5-and-visual.aspx)
2. [Web Application Installer in WiX](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/web-application-installer-in-wix)
3. [WiX and DTF: Using a Custom Action to list available web sites on IIS](http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/24/)
4. [Installing a Web Application to an Existing IIS Website using Wix3](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/installing-web-application-existing-iis-website-using-wix3)

In short:
Create a Website element in your Product element:

```
<Product>
    <iis:WebSite Id="SelectedWebSite" Description="[WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION]" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" SiteId="[WEBSITE_ID]">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
    </iis:WebSite>
</Product>
```

Create an Include WebSites.wxi with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <Property Id="WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WebSiteDescription" Name="WebSiteDescription" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\!(loc.CompanyName)\[ProductName]\Install" Type="raw" />
  </Property>
  <Property Id="WEBSITE_ID">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WebSiteID" Name="WebSiteID" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\!(loc.CompanyName)\[ProductName]\Install" Type="raw" />
  </Property>
  <Property Id="WEBSITE_PATH">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WebSitePath" Name="WebSitePath" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\!(loc.CompanyName)\[ProductName]\Install" Type="raw" />
  </Property>
  <Property Id="WEBSITE_VD">
    <RegistrySearch Id="WebSiteVD" Name="WebSiteVD" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\!(loc.CompanyName)\[ProductName]\Install" Type="raw" />
  </Property>
  <CustomTable Id="AvailableWebSites">
    <Column Id="WebSiteID" Category="Identifier" PrimaryKey="yes" Type="int" Width="4"/>
    <Column Id="WebSiteDescription" Category="Text" Type="string" PrimaryKey="no"/>
    <Column Id="WebSitePath" Category="Text" Type="string" PrimaryKey="no" Nullable="yes"/>
    <Row>
      <Data Column="WebSiteID">0</Data>
      <Data Column="WebSiteDescription">Dummy</Data>
      <Data Column="WebSitePath"></Data>
    </Row>
  </CustomTable>
</Include>
```

Create the CustomAction described [here](http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2011/02/26/creating-a-web-application-installer-with-wix-3.5-and-visual-once-more.aspx).

Create a wxs file with your AppPool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" 
  xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
    <Fragment>
    <Component Id="WebVirtualDirComponent" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" KeyPath="yes">
      <iis:WebAppPool 
        Id="YourAppPoolName" 
        Name="[VD][WEBSITE_ID]" 
        ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" 
        IdleTimeout="0" 
        RecycleMinutes="0" 
        ManagedPipelineMode="integrated"/>
      <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VDir" Alias="[VD]" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" WebSite="SelectedWebSite">
        <iis:WebApplication Id="NotizBrowserWebApp" WebAppPool="YourAppPoolName" Name="[VD][WEBSITE_ID]" />
        <iis:WebDirProperties Id="NotizBrowserProps" AnonymousAccess="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" DefaultDocuments="-" Execute="yes" Script="yes" Read="yes"/>
      </iis:WebVirtualDir>
    </Component>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: "Create the CustomAction described here" link is dead. Here is an archived snapshot of that link https://web.archive.org/web/20160315164757/http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2011/02/26/creating-a-web-application-installer-with-wix-3.5-and-visual-once-more.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but hopefully someone will be benefited with this.

You don't need a CustomAction to make this work.

It is simple like this:

```
<Component Id="WebSite" Guid="PUT-YOUR-GUID-HERE">
    <CreateFolder/>
    <iis:WebSite Id="WebSite" Directory="WebSiteRoot" Description="[WEBSITEDESCRIPTION]" >
        <iis:WebApplication Id="WebSiteApplication" Name="[WEBSITEDESCRIPTION]" WebAppPool="MyAppPool" />
    </iis:WebSite>
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="MyAppPool" Name="[APPPOOLNAME]" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>
</Component>
```

You need to update the "Internal" WebApplication of the WebSite.

You don't need to have the "WebSite Description" and "WebApplication Name" equal, but that will help you to understand what is going on.