# How to use if..else condition in Wix toolset?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

Here is my requirement: if web.config file exists in D:\default\website\web.config I have to copy some files to D:\default\website location else copy the same files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot location.

How to write this condition in .wxs file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to nest a [FileSearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/filesearch.html) element under a [DirectorySearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directorysearch.html) element in order to detect the presence of a file.

```
<Property Id="WEB_CONFIG_UNDER_D">
    <DirectorySearch Path="D:\default\website"
        Depth="0"
        AssignToProperty="no"
        Id="DefaultWebsiteSearch">
        <FileSearch Name="web.config"
            Id="webconfigSearch" />
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

You can now check if the property `WEB_CONFIG_UNDER_D` exists and then use different TargetDirectories based on that property.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to properly create a new website, you'll have to take a much more complicated route as described in the SO question [wix installer / Create web-site and assign the new or exisiting web app pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389208/wix-installer-create-web-site-and-assign-the-new-or-exisiting-web-app-pool/18574870#18574870).

Comment: How to check WEB_CONFIG_UNDER_D exists or not using <?if?> ..<?else?>

Comment: I have some set of files which I want to copy to D:\ drive if web.config file exists, if not I have to copy to C:\

Comment: The [<if><else><endif>](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) construct is used in combination with preprocessor variables. This means that this construct only makes sense if you want to check conditions on the developer machine. The property described above can be simply used as a feature condition. Create two features, one which installs to D:, the other to C: